# Time difference between renderer and main process

Tags: node.js, electron, chromium, dst

I believe this could be related to daylight saving time but not entirely sure.

Essentially i have a file that i share between both the renderer and main process.

```
'use strict';

const time = new Date();

module.exports = () => console.log(time);
```

When i require and execute in main process i get

`2017-07-10T12:34:17.613Z`

However when i require and execute in the renderer process i get

`Mon Jul 10 2017 13:44:08 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`

When i execute `node -e "console.log(new Date())"` in node console i get the same output as the main process which makes sense, so i assume chromium is managing dates differently to node.

I guess the time difference and my inability to explain it points to two questions:

- Hour difference - Why is there an hour difference? Is this some affect of DST? If so can the renderer and main process be brought into sync?
- Second difference - Why is there also second differences? When the main and renderer process require the same file they share the same cache right? So should get the exact same date and log it?

Any help on the two points would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by new Date () is the same in both contexts, but it is automatically converted into a string in two different ways.

In the main process, console.log () probably makes use of [toISOString ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

In the renderer process, an implicit call to [toString ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) occurs:

> The toString() method always returns a string representation of the
>   date in American English. JavaScript calls the toString() method
>   automatically when a date is to be represented as a text value or when
>   a date is referred to in a string concatenation.

Comment: I think the OP is concerned about the actual time difference and not the format.

Comment: There is no actual hour difference, the Z prefix indicates universal time in the first case, while the time is shown according to the locale time zone in the second case.

Comment: Spot on. Interesting to see such a difference in default methods used. My understanding was Chromium and Node are both V8 powered, i would have expected such behavior to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the second difference, I did some investigation and it seems that the cache is handled at process level. Actually, I found some useful information on this page:

[Deep dive into Electron’s main and renderer processes](https://medium.com/@ccnokes/deep-dive-into-electrons-main-and-renderer-processes-7a9599d5c9e2)

> So for example, let’s say I have a module that holds some state that I
>   require in both my main and renderer process.
>
> If I increment in my renderer, the count in the renderer will be 1,
>   but it’ll still be 0 in the main process. The two processes don’t
>   share memory or state. There are literally two instances of that
>   module running.

In order to display the same time in both processes, a possibly better way would be to use a shared global variable to store the string returned by applying .toISOString() or toString() to new Date (), then explicitely call console.log() from each process.

In main process:

```
global.time = new Date ().toString ();
console.log (global.time);
```

In renderer process:

```
console.log (remote.getGlobal ('time'));
```